# Преобразовать строковое выражение в математическое

Tags: c#

Допустим есть переменная типа string в которую юзер забивает некую формулу.

Пример:1+2*3

Как можно выполнить это выражение и присвоить значение 7 переменной?

Я нашел решение через создание COM объекта, но может есть еще более рациональное решение?

```
ScriptControl sc = new ScriptControl();
        sc.Language = "VBScript";
        string expression = str;
        var i=(long) sc.Eval(expression);
```

Comment: Предъявите полные требования. Скобки? Функции? Полный список операций? Разрядность? Чему должно быть равно `1 / 3 * 3`? Невозможность удаления файлов злонамеренным пользователем, вписывающим всякую фигню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это одно из самых простых для написания. Из [вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net) ещё:

```
double result = (double) new DataTable().Compute("1 + 2 * 7", null);
double result = (double) HtmlPage.Window.Eval("15 + 35"); //работает только d silverlight
```

Или ещё можно заюзать [библи](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)[отеки](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/381509/Math-Parser-NET-Csharp)