# Простой парсер математических выражений

Tags: c#, интерпретатор

Допустим мы записали в текстовое поле (tb1) число 13, тогда при нажатии кнопки мы можем прописать такой код

```
Message.Show((double.Parse(tb1.Text)).ToString());
```

В чем смысл? Смысл в том, что мы конвертировали строку "13" в double "13". И при выводе сообщения мы вновь увидим "13", почему понятно. Давайте тогда допустим, что мы записали в текстовое поле "13 + 2". Тогда строчка написанного кода уже не сработает. Выдаст ошибку. Есть ли какое-нибудь готовое решение, которое принимало бы строки такого вида и возвращало бы double.

Comment: Или вот: [Создать примитивный парсер математических выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/423283/186999)

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: Ещё есть [фокус с DataTable](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688804/179763)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можете попробовать NuGet пакет `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var expression = "2 * 6";
            var result = Parse(expression);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        static double Parse(string expression)
        {
            return CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<double>(expression).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как использовать данный пакет с функциями, например, cos(6), sqrt(16), pow(5, 2)?

Comment: var expression = "Pow(5, 2)";
            var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System.Math");
            return CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<double>(expression, options).Result;

Comment: Примеры https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: Стоит оформить ответ в вопросе-цели дубликата - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/436942/ - там сейчас только самописные парсеры в качестве ответов

Answer (score 0):

Метод Parse из строки делает число, а "13 + 2" - не число записанное в строке, а "инструкции". Попробуйте методом Split() разделять строку на 2 подстроки, и уже работать с ними.

Comment: Это костыль, братишка, и еще не оптимизированный