# Есть ли в C# аналог eval?

Tags: c#

Проблема заключается в том, что надо получать на вход формулу, которую вводит пользователь, и эту формулу надо использовать для дальнейших вычислений.

Насколько могу предположить, при считывании с помощью `ReadLine()` это будет строка.

Есть ли в **C#** нечто похожее на `eval()` (например, Питоний)? Есть ли другие варианты, как формулу, содержащуюся в строке, использовать для подсчета (сделав из нее метод)? (Формула произвольная.)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813932/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/813962#813962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть C# Scripting.
Отвечал уже [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813932/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/813962#813962)

Выглядит примерно так:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var expression = "2 * 6";
            var result = Parse(expression);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        static double Parse(string expression)
        {
            return CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<double>(expression).Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: если вы уже отвечали это, почему бы не закрыть дубликатом? Зачем копипастить ответ? :)

Comment: Извините, я не знаю как это делать, буду рад если закроете дубликатом

Comment: под вопросом есть ссылочка `закрыть` - нажимаете её, выбираете первый пункт (где вопрос уже имеет решение), ищете там свой ответ и закрываете

Comment: У меня нет такой кнопки, то, что указано в ответе сейчас не решает проблему ТС

Comment: Это странно, что нет кнопки. Там 2 ответа и оба считают выражение. В любом случае, ваш ответ уже принят автором, значит, его проблема решена.

Comment: Если у вас нет кнопки "закрыть" - нажимайте кнопку "тревога" и выбирайте пункт "должен быть закрыт"

Comment: А не проще ли ответить на вопрос? чем заниматься формализмом, тем более 100% одинаковых вопросов не бывает, бывают идентичные ответы на разные вопросы, имхо..